# Why isn't the dist-upgrade showing up in update-manager?

Tags: apt, upgrade, tmpfs

Ubuntu 14.04 was released on 17 April 2014, and today it is already the 18th.

Why isn't the distribution showing up in my ubuntu update-manager?

(I have set it so it will anounce every new version)

The content of `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` contains a link to:  http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
Is it correct, that it doesn't show trusty yet?

---

So the only solution I see for me would be to set it manually with:

```
source /etc/lsb-release
sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.$DISTRIB_CODENAME 
sudo sed -i s/$DISTRIB_CODENAME/trusty/g /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and then upgrade.

Do I have to disable the partner repos in this case?

```
#deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
```

Comment: What ubuntu release are you currently using?

Comment: saucy, I updated the question

Comment: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu looks like it's currently updating. Some files under http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/ were updated only a few minutes ago.

Comment: I solved this on one of my laptops coming from Saucy 13.10 (reason: a virtual /tmp partition; see answer below). On another Notebook coming from 12.04 I have the same problem now, which must have another reason. not even `do-release-upgrade` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out, that it is a problem when `/tmp` is mounted as `noexec`

```
$ grep tmp /etc/fstab

tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   nosuid,noatime,noexec,mode=1777,size=999M       0       0
```

(I did this, cause I use an SSD and with 8GB Ram I am never short on it.)

I unmounted it with

```
umount -l /tmp
```

and commented out the line in /etc/fstab

```
#tmpfs   /tmp    tmpfs   nosuid,noatime,noexec,mode=1777,size=999M
```

now it shows up in update-manager or

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Answer (score 2):

> Canonical will not start notify LTS desktop users of an update until
>   July, when the first point release (14.04.1) is set to go live

*source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04*

so the new version 14.04 LTS  is not set yet in  http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts

---

I couldn't find out why

```
gksu update-manager -d
```

didn't work, but I created an [updated version of the meta-release File](https://gist.github.com/rubo77/11079798).

Try updating your `/etc/update-manager/meta-release` with this Link:

```
# default location for the meta-release file

[METARELEASE]
URI = http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release
#URI_LTS = http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts
URI_LTS = https://gist.githubusercontent.com/rubo77/11079798/raw/64967886425a0f9f172a3834ddaff34a2a75987d/gistfile1.txt
URI_UNSTABLE_POSTFIX = -development
URI_PROPOSED_POSTFIX = -proposed
```

**NOTE:** You have to change that back, When the upgrade is done, otherwise there will never be suggested the next update!

Answer (score 2):

> Canonical will not start notify LTS desktop users of an update until
>   July, when the first point release (14.04.1) is set to go live

*source: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/04/upgrade-ubuntu-14-04-12-04*

so the new version 14.04 LTS  is not set yet in  http://changelogs.ubuntu.com/meta-release-lts

---

So usually this will update your system to the latest release even if it is not yes offfered for LTS releases:

```
gksu update-manager -d
```

If that doesn't work, edit the file `cat /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades` and set:

```
Prompt=normal
```

or in one line:

```
sudo sed -i s/Prompt=lts/Prompt=normal/g /etc/update-manager/release-upgrades
```

Comment: `sudo update-manager -d` worked for me! My `release-upgrades` says `prompt=lts`.